How to run a specific command as another user, without password, including passing arguments?
Due to the complex nature of Postfix sending mail as a custom user@address, and its interaction with openDKIM, when I send mail from bash, I execute a script mailSender.sh containing :
TO=$1
USER=$2

cat >/message.txt <<EOL
To: ${TO}

Message body
EOL
su -c "cat /message.txt | /sendmail -t ${TO}" ${USER}

This script sends a message to $TO, set by the first shell argument, from $USER, set by the second shell argument.
This works as I require when run as root. The above set-up may seem overly complicated to send an email. This is not my question here. I have spent much time arriving at the above setup, and it has the form it does due to the interplay of bash, Postfix and OpenDKIM.
My question is, how can I achieve the effect of the above shell script, executed by a user other than root, without a password prompt ?
The furthest I have progressed is, using the visudo command, to add the line
mydesireduser ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /mailSender.sh

to the sudoers file. This words correctly if I login as another user:
su mydesireduser

and run the script without arguments
/mailSender.sh

As soon as I add arguments however, I am asked for a password. If I specify fixed arguments in the sudoers file:
mydesireduser ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /mailSender.sh fixedTo fixedSender

I can execute with the arguments set in the sudoers file.
How can I achieve the same result as when I run the script as root ? If with the sudoers file, how can I allow arbitrary arguments to be passed as input ? Is there a means without using the sudoers file ?
Help is appreciated.
Environment specs
I am using bash on ubuntu (focal fossa).

Try using sudo in your script instead of su, adapting the syntax of course. visudo only applies to sudo, not to su.
